# Failed dependencies error during installation of neo4j on Centos7

Tags: neo4j, centos7, failed-installation, cypher-shell

I'm trying to install community version of neo4j server.
My server is running Centos7

```
$ hostnamectl
 Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

I have jdk-17_linux-x64_bin.rpm  installed.

When I run

```
rpm -ivh neo4j-5.3.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

I get the following error message:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
cypher-shell >= 5.0 is needed by neo4j-5.3.0-1.noarch
cypher-shell < 6.0 is needed by neo4j-5.3.0-1.noarch
```

Searching for "cypher-shell >= 5.0 " online returns 0 results.

What am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: As reported at the link https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/rpm/ "It is important to note that using this method will mean that the offline machine will not receive the dependencies that are normally downloaded and installed automatically when using yum for installing Neo4j; Neo4j Cypher Shell and Java". So you have to download cypher-shell RPM at the link https://neo4j.com/download-center/#cypher-shell and install it before neo4j

Comment: @Saxon, thank you, it worked!. I'd be happy to accept your answer if you add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As reported at the link neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/rpm "It is important to note that using this method will mean that the offline machine will not receive the dependencies that are normally downloaded and installed automatically when using yum for installing Neo4j; Neo4j Cypher Shell and Java". So you have to download cypher-shell RPM at the link neo4j.com/download-center/#cypher-shell and install it before neo4j